# Get value from raffle system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have here a raffle system where it randomly generates the name that determines the winner. But I have to use the generated name for updating purposes on my database, so I was thinking of getting the value of the generated name and put it in a PHP variable so I can use it on a `POST Form` or `<a> link`.

Reason for doing this is because I have to assign the winner either to group A or group B on my database.

Here is the HTML form, where the name of the winner will be shown when the button is clicked:

```
<img id="loader" style="display:none" src="loader.gif" height="30"/> Winner is: <strong> <span id="span_name_winner"></span> <span id="span_lname_winner"></span></strong></h1>      
<input type="button" id="get_winner" value="Get Winner" class="btn btn-danger"/>
```

I have here a pre-variables assigned in the script:

```
var seq = 10;
var pre_seq = 0;
var timeout;
```

And when the button is clicked, this script will run:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#get_winner").click(function() {
        $("#loader").show();
        pre_seq = 0;
        timeout = setTimeout('make_random()', 100);
    });

});
```

That will also determine the action script below. This script generates and trigger of showing the name, and also shows first random string of characters before showing the name of the winner. The `raffle_winner.php` has the array of names:

```
function make_random()
{   

    if(pre_seq > seq) {

        $.post('raffle_winner.php', null,
            function(e) {
            $("#loader").hide();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
             $("#span_lname_winner").text("");
             $("#span_name_winner").text(e.winner);
            }
        );

    } else {

        var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var name = "";
        var lname = "";

         $("#span_lname_winner").text("");
         $("#span_name_winner").text("");
        for( var i=0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            name = $("#span_name_winner").text();
            name += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
             $("#span_name_winner").text(name);
        }

        for( var i=0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            lname = $("#span_lname_winner").text();
            lname += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
             $("#span_lname_winner").text(lname);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout('make_random()', 500);
        pre_seq++;
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I get the value of the generated name and put it in a PHP variable so I can use it for my further SQL queries.

Comment: `setTimeout(makeRandom, 100);` otherwise you're forcing an eval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. I added this code to my script

```
$("#span_winner").val(e.winner);
```

so I can get the value of the generated random name and assign it to this html input below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="span_winner" name="hiddenname">
```

Answer (score 0):

When the form is sent to the server using post. just grab the POST array in php and take out the value you need like this:

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){ 
  $your_php_variable = $_POST['the name of your HTML input box']; 
}
```

Just remember to wrap your input boxes in a set of form tags and make sure its method attribute is set to post and the action is set to the location of the PHP script you're using and your good to go.